# Change animation css attribute with javascript onmousemove?

Tags: javascript, css, events, animation

So im making this little trick on my website that when you move your cursor on the screen it changes the speed at which the logo of the site rotates.

For some reason i cannot seem to be able to change the animation attribute of the element im rotating on the fly with js. I also added a textbox to display the mouse X position which im using for the speed of the roation of the logo, and it displays the string correctly so i guess its probably a silly syntax error.

```
<style type="text/css">
#logorota {

    animation: 15s linear 0s normal none infinite rot_inf;    
}

@keyframes rot_inf {

    0% {    
        transform: rotate(0deg);        
    }

    100% {  
        transform: rotate(359deg);      
    }
}


</style>


<body>
<script>            
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);

        document.onmousemove = mousePos, logoSpeed;

            function mousePos (x) {

                var mouseX = x.pageX / 100;

                document.mouseMovs.mousePos.value = mouseX + "s linear 0s normal none infinite rot_inf"; //displays the string correctly.
            };


            function logoSpeed (x)
            {

                var mouseX = x.pageX / 100;
                document.getElementById('logorota').style.animation = mouseX + "s linear 0s normal none infinite rot_inf";

            };                
    </script>

    <div>
        <img src="logorota.png" id="logorota">

        <form name="mouseMovs">
        <input type="text" name="mousePos" /> Mouse position <br />     
        </form>
</div>
</body>
```

EDIT: Added http://jsfiddle.net/ot4zyp30/

Comment: have you got a jsfiddle displaying your issue?

Comment: mmkay let me give it a go, im using netbeans.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ot4zyp30/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution here for webkit, working right. It is a lil tricky to change these values on the fly.

Attached to 'mousemove', this script adds / removes the animation rule & class continiously and alters some values so it rotates smooth enough.

Theres bunch of stuff you wanna change if you use this. Atleast make sure the stylesheet index is good etc. in this case i use 1 since thats the jsFiddle stylesheet index.

EDIT: works on firefox now too

http://jsfiddle.net/9nj4dgeq/

```
//

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {

    Rotator.init(event, document.getElementsByClassName("img")[0]);

}, false);

//

var Rotator = {

    init: function(event, element_) {



        var element = element_,
            compatibility = {
                prefixes: ["-webkit-", "-moz-"],
            },
            browserPrefix,
            browserEvent = event.clientX,
            stylesheet = 0;

        for (var k in compatibility) {

            if (k === "prefixes") {

                for (var i = 0; i < compatibility[k].length; i += 1) {

                    if (window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(compatibility[k][i] + "transform") !== null) {

                        browserPrefix = compatibility.prefixes[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.rotate(element, browserPrefix, browserEvent, stylesheet);
    },

    rotate: function(element_, browserPrefix_, browserEvent_, stylesheet_) {

        var element = element_,
            className = element.className,
            browserPrefix = browserPrefix_,
            browserEvent = browserEvent_,
            stylesheet = stylesheet_,
            blanks = [
                "@" + browserPrefix + "keyframes ",
                " {from{" + browserPrefix + "transform:rotate( ",
                "deg);}to{" + browserPrefix + "transform:rotate(",
                "deg);}}",
                ".",
                "{" + browserPrefix + "animation-name:",
                ";" + browserPrefix + "animation-timing-function:linear;" + browserPrefix + "animation-iteration-count:infinite;" + browserPrefix + "animation-duration:",
                "s}"],
            name = "rotating" + browserEvent,
            speed = String(browserEvent / 100),
            transform = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(browserPrefix + "transform"),
            values, a, b, angle, toAngle;

        if (transform !== "none") {

            values = transform.split('(')[1];
            values = values.split(')')[0];
            values = values.split(',');
            a = values[0];
            b = values[1];

            angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
        }

        toAngle = 360 + angle;

        document.styleSheets[stylesheet].insertRule(blanks[0] + name + blanks[1] + angle + blanks[2] +

        (function () {

            if (!toAngle) {

                return 10;

            } else {

                return toAngle;
            }
        }()) + blanks[3], 0);

        document.styleSheets[stylesheet].insertRule(blanks[4] + className + blanks[5] + name + blanks[6] + speed + blanks[7], 0);

        if (document.styleSheets[stylesheet].cssRules.length > 8) {
            for (var rules = document.styleSheets[stylesheet].cssRules.length; rules > 2; rules -= 1) {
                document.styleSheets[stylesheet].deleteRule([rules] - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the jsfiddle it doesn't work with firefox, think i could tweak it a little bit to make it work?

Comment: yeah it seems you only have to change vendor prefixes to -moz- and the event part, from event.x to event.clientX. I can write a cross-browser version of this today.

Comment: ok i did a lil work on it. http://jsfiddle.net/9nj4dgeq/ incase you still need it.